# What is the outer hull of Enterprise (NCC-1701) constructed from?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, composition

What is the outer hull of Enterprise (NCC-1701) supposed to be constructed from?  Are the later vessels in the franchise made from the same material(s)? I'm hoping for a Gene R. answer, but if not, the next best example from the franchise would suffice.

Comment: Based on the Memory Alpha article for Hull, and particularly after examining all the articles for substances listed in the [Hull materials](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hull#Hull_materials) section, I doubt this is a well-known detail. If it is stated anywhere, it is probably in a novel or other non-canonical source. I've also looked through the articles for NCC-1701 and Constitution-class starships with no success.

Comment: There may be an answer later on, but TOS-era was occasionally mixed up on its own technology - I'd be surprised if it was mentioned _and_ consistent in TOS.

Comment: @Izkata Memory Alpha encompasses *all* of Star Trek canon. If it was ever mentioned canonically, it would probably be there. Of course, with Memory Alpha being a wiki, there is always a possibility of inadvertent omission. However, this would likely mean that searching for a canonical answer will probably be non-trivial.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you only interested in the *primary universe* NCC-1701 or would you accept an answer from the alternate universe created by J.J. Abrams if one becomes available?

Comment: I believe the outer hull is composed of Duranium and possibly other alloys...can't remember where/which/when this is stated in canon though.

Comment: lol. I'm interested in the closest thing to gospel. If Gene didn't specify, Rick or JJ would be acceptable. ;)

Comment: @MajorStackings Actually, I think you should probably choose one or state that you're interested in either. It's quite possible - even likely - that the real-world answers (were either of these universes real) would be different. J.J. Abrams has mentioned that scans of the Narada led to technological advancements that did not happen so early in the prime universe - explaining why the Enterprise and other technological marvels in the alternate reality look so different from the prime universe. It's likely these premature advancements may have included new alloys for starship hulls as well.

Comment: I heard from a reliable source that it is made of corbomite.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[Star Trek: The Next Generation: Technical Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671704273) (Paperback) by Rick Sternbach, Michael Okuda** indicate the hulls of Federation ships were a hollow structure reinforced with structural integrity force fields for faster than light travel and woven composite materials using duranium and tritanium/titanium alloys. This is the only publication I have which would have any level of canon reference.

> The outer hull of NX-class starships were lined with duranium. (ENT: "The Xindi") - Memory Alpha

Tritanium will frequently reappear in Star Trek as a construction material for starship hulls. TOS Spock states that tritanium is 21.4 times as hard as diamonds.

> Tritanium alloy was a widely-used construction material. The bulkheads of Enterprise were composed of tritanium. (ENT: "Dead Stop") In the 24th century, Federation starships, specifically Galaxy-class, Intrepid-class and Raven-type, also had tritanium bulkheads. (TNG: "Where Silence Has Lease"; VOY: "Year of Hell, Part II", "The Raven", "Repentance") **- Memory Alpha**

Comment: Does this state how far back those alloys were used? TNG occurred centuries after TOS, so it's quite probable TNG-era ships would have used different alloys, unless the manual explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: It specified the design of the hull were consistent with the Constitution class cruisers, but since it was written long before NX-01, we cannot be sure the technology existed for the ENT crew.

Comment: Good stuff, then. Might want to add it to your answer?

Comment: @Iszi By "centuries" you mean..."century".

Comment: @NominSim True enough, though I believe my point still stands. I'm glad to hear it's still covered, though.

Comment: Yep, no indication this, nor duranium, were used for this specific model.

Comment: I think the problem that any educated fan of the franchise will realize at some point is that use of these super heavy metals for construction of space vehicles is ridiculously impracticle because of their high density. In space, you want to use the least amount of energy possible for propulsion, and we know energy consumption was a serious matter, as Capt. Kirk needed to sign a certificate of consumption frequently in TOS. Thus, the only reasonable conclusion is that all these exotic, super hard metals are alloyed with high-strength, low density metals, i.e. titanium or possibly aluminum, in

Comment: we do know that the hulls are ferromagnetic from several scenes where magnetised boots are used to walk around on them. As to Merritt's comment, I'm not so sure. The main reason to conserve weight in current spacecraft is the cost of lifting weight through the planetary gravity well of Earth (or any gravity well, were other planets involved). For ships that exist exclusively in space, are never intended to be grounded, weight would not be a problem, mass would be of course. But you'd probably rather have a thin layer of extremely dense material than a thick layer of less dense material.

Answer (score 7):

[Cast Rodinium](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rodinium)  was the hardest substance known to Federation science at the time of "[Balance of Terror](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Balance_of_Terror_%28episode%29)" and was used on the outposts at the Neutral Zone. Spock crushed some plasma-imploded cast Rodinium in his hand during that pre-battle meeting.

Comment: The Memory Alpha website calls it Cast Rhodinium, not Castrodinium.

Comment: Hi @mytai01 I've converted your answer into a comment. I did this because although you seem to have enough reputation, it looks like you meant to reply to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall from blueprints back in the 60's that the ENTERPRISE hull was ferro-cement. . .an attainable product and workable in space. TOS had the ship built in orbit. . .

Comment: Are you able to add any links or pictures to back this up, as recollections do not make for a good answer on here